# Using ! in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can some one please explain the usage `!` in the following ruby example:

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :layout => ! request.xhr? }
    end
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply logical `not`.

```
request.xhr?
=> true

!request.xhr?
=> false
```

Comment: To further expand, `request.xhr?` would be true when the request is an ajax call, so in the above code this is setting :layout to false for ajax responses in order to render an html fragment (e.g. some portion of html to be inserted into the page, but not including header etc)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to render a layout when the request comes from AJAX. then use `:layout => !request.xhr?`