# what is ^ used for in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of caret symbol( ^ ) in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163093/use-of-caret-symbol-in-ruby)

So I was playing around with some code and I tried to play around with the power operator.  So I thought that perhaps I could use the caret (`^`) for this purpose, but after using it in:

```
for i in 0..10
  puts "#{i}   #{1^i}\n"
end
```

I got some really funky results

```
0   -  1
1   -  0
2   -  3
3   -  2
4   -  5
5   -  4
6   -  7
7   -  6
8   -  9
9   -  8
10  -  11
```

The only pattern I see is -1 on an odd number and +1 on an even number, but then when I try:

```
for i in 0..10
  puts "#{i}   #{2^i}\n"
end
```

i get:

```
0   -  2
1   -  3
2   -  0
3   -  1
4   -  6
5   -  7
6   -  4
7   -  5
8   -  10
9   -  11
10  -  8
```

wth!  So then I kept going up to `4^i` and plotted them, the `1^i & 3^i` came out with [decent patterns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg40B.png) but `2^i & 4^i` were just all over the place with no visible patterns (though highly unlikely) with just 11 plotting points, so I've come to you ladies and gents asking you:

What on earth is `^` used for?!

Comment: I guess it’s the XOR operator.

Comment: Sometimes i dont get SO community. Why does that silly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464250/using-in-ruby question got +2 upvotes, while this one continue getting downvotes?

Comment: @ted Questions get downvoted for being poorly researched, failing to include enough information, or being difficult to understand. This is a case of the former, since a quick web search for "caret operator ruby" would have answered the question (with a stack overflow question, no less).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In most programming languages, `^` is the XOR operator ([Exclusive Or in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)). XOR is one of the most essential operations in the CPU, it often employed to zero registers (think of `a ^= a`) because it is fast and has a short opcode.

For the power function, you have to use e.g. `**` (e.g. in ruby), `java.lang.Math.pow`, `math.pow`, `pow` etc.

In fact, I couldn't name a programming language that uses `^`. It is used in LaTeX for formatting (as superscript, not power function, technically). But the two variants I see all the time are `**` (as the power function is directly related to multiplication) and `pow(base, exp)`.

Note that you can compute integer powers of 2 faster using shifts.

Comment: If you're going to answer a Ruby question, it might be prudent to give the Ruby syntax, not the Java et al — for the record, exponent operator in Ruby is `**`.

Comment: I've used Ruby once only, some time ago. That the behavior was XOR was obvious enought. Thanks, I'll add this.

Comment: `3 << 4 is extremely fast, much faster than 3 ** 16` Have you checked this? I assume scripting languages like python and ruby implements binary multiplication/powering;

Comment: @ted But `3 << 4 != 3 ** 16`.

Comment: @Gumbo, it had been a comment to the quote up to the moment the answer was edited. That was the answer-author words and i've just asked wheather it was tested somehow even if it's not equal.

Comment: I removed that part, because it was not correct. It's multiplication with powers of 2 and 2^n that you can compute faster using shifts. And no, as far as I know scripting languages do not perform this kind of optimization. In a quick experiment, `<<4` was around 10% than `*16`.
Ruby also didn't notice that the whole benchmark loop was pointless and could be optimized to a NOOP; any decent optimizing compiler should have done that.

Comment: I have to question your "most" qualifier. Maybe in some circles it's common, but "most" people I know are using a C-derived language.

Comment: @Maxx? `^` is XOR in C, too: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: *n fact, I couldn't name a programming language that uses `^`*. Both bc and lua use `^` to do exponentiation.

Comment: AWK uses `^` as well.